# How to change file permissions with WMI?

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

I'm want to do the equivalent of what is described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/security-windows.html) from a script. Basically, I want to take ownership of the file, and set the permissions to OWNER/Full Control.

It seems to me that using WMI from a vbs script is the most portable way. That is, I'd like to avoid xcacls, icacls and other tools that either require a download, or are supported only on some versions of windows.

After googling around, I found this code for taking ownership:

```
'connect to WMI namespace on local machine 
Set objServices = 
GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}") 
'get a reference to data file 
strFile = Wscript.Arguments(0) 
Set objFile = objServices.Get("CIM_DataFile.Name='" & strFile & "'") 
If  objFile.TakeOwnership = 0 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "File ownership successfully changed" 
Else 
    Wscript.Echo "File ownership transfer operation" 
End If
```

The pieces I'm still missing is setting the permissions, and having it work on relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using `TakeOwnership` in the `CIM_DataFile` class, I'd assume you could just use [ChangeSecurityPermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to change the permissions, which is in the same class.

And you might be able to use [GetAbsolutePathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx1xa64f%28VS.85%29.aspx) to convert your relative paths to absolute paths before you use them.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the hints from ho1's answer, I googled around some more, and eventually came up with this:

This script finds the current user SID, then takes ownership and changes the permissions on the file given in argv[0] to Full Control only to current user.

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}") 

Function GetCurrentUserSID
    ' Get user name '
    Set colComputer = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

    ' Looping over one item '
    For Each objComputer in colComputer
      currentUserName = objComputer.UserName
    Next

    Set AccountSIDs = GetObject("Winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_AccountSID") 
    For Each AccountSID In AccountSIDs
        AccountKey = AccountSID.Element 
        Set objAccount = GetObject("Winmgmts:"+AccountKey) 
        strName = objAccount.Domain & "\" & objAccount.Name
        If strName = currentUserName Then ' that's it 
            SIDKey = AccountSID.Setting
            Set SID = GetObject("Winmgmts:" + SIDKey)
            GetCurrentUserSID = SID.BinaryRepresentation
            Exit For 
        End If   
    Next 
End Function

Function LimitPermissions(path, SID)
    Set objFile = objWMI.Get("CIM_DataFile.Name='" & path & "'") 

    Set Trustee = GetObject("Winmgmts:Win32_Trustee").SpawnInstance_ 
    Trustee.SID = SID

    Set ACE = getObject("Winmgmts:Win32_Ace").Spawninstance_ 
    ACE.AccessMask = 2032127 ' Full Control
    ACE.AceFlags = 3 
    ACE.AceType = 0
    ACE.Trustee = Trustee 

    Set objSecDescriptor = GetObject("Winmgmts:Win32_SecurityDescriptor").SpawnInstance_ 
    objSecDescriptor.DACL = Array(ACE) 

    objFile.ChangeSecurityPermissions objSecDescriptor, 4 
End Function

Function TakeOwnership(path)
    Set objFile = objWMI.Get("CIM_DataFile.Name='" & path & "'") 
    TakeOwnership = objFile.TakeOwnership
End Function

' Main '

strFilename = Wscript.Arguments(0) 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(strFilename)

SID = GetCurrentUserSID

TakeOwnership path
LimitPermissions path, SID
```