# Need Windows chmod777 Equivalent

Tags: c#, java, windows, permissions

I need to set permissions on a file, so that all users on the system can read and write to it. This is related to an installer, so I do not know the user names ahead of time. The installer runs as admin, so the log file requires admin access afterwards. So I need to explicitly set the permissions, during the install, so that referencing programs don't need to be run as admin.

In essence, I'm looking for a solution that can give me the equivalent of chmod777 in Windows.

I would prefer a solution that works for both Win7 and WinXP. I would like a solution that is through command line, which I can then script. Or a solution using C# or java.

Comment: Windows applications should not require global read/write to files in Program Files.

Comment: I agree with @sixlettervariables. Why aren't you storing the file in `ProgramData` (aka `All Users\Application Data`) instead?

Comment: What have you tried?   A quick google of set windows file permissions c# gives a ton of links on how to do this.

Comment: As others stated, if people need read and write access to a file then storing it under Program Files is not correct place.

Comment: I left out details to keep things succinct. The program installs files that are used by several different programs. The file that needs to the permission change is a log file. One of the programs is requiring to be run as "admin" else it crashes. Through troubleshooting, it was determined that the issue is related to how the file is created.  Since the installer requires to be run as admin, the file has permissions set accordingly. Changing the permissions on the log file, solves the program from having to be run as admin. Which is the desired behavior.

Comment: @VenomFangs which doesn't change the fact that `%ProgramFiles%` is abolutely the *wrong* place to be writing log files (`%ProgramData%` or `%APPDATA%` or even `%TEMP%` would all be better), but if you can't fix that huge problem, see my answer.

Comment: I updated the question to get rid of the program files reference, and give details related to the admin status. The log file is actually in programdata. My attempt to simplify the question was mistaken :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All modern Windows OS's have a build-in group called "Everyone" that is the equivalent of the UNIX "other" permissions. Even non-logged-in users are part of the Everyone group. From there you can give "Everyone" read, write, and modify ("change") permissions. You could, if you were completely insane, give Everyone "full control" but that actually allows them to take ownership and change the permissions, so *please* don't do that :)

To actually apply these permissions you can use a number of techniques

- From a command-line, you can run `cacls <file name> /g Everyone:RWC`
- In .NET you can create an ACL for the NT Account with `WellKnownSidType.WorldSid` then apply it to a file, as in this article: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c513ca26-9bf8-4e39-a993-4ebf90aaece6/
- You can use WMI, as per [How to change file permissions with WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085757/how-to-change-file-permissions-with-wmi) (should work in any WMI-enabled language)
- You could use the native Win32 file permission APIs (via P/Invoke or JNI).

Comment: Note that other, more specific groups, might also be useful here; "Users" will include everyone logged in (but not anonymous) which should cover anyone capable of running an application.

Comment: Awesome. I'm going to try this. I saw the refernece to icacls for Win7 and noticed cacls for XP. I'll test to see if I can use cacls for both. If so, I should be good and will accept the solution.

Comment: cacls still exists, though its deprecated, and should still work at least through windows 7.  icacls as added in 2003 and has slightly different (but more complete) syntax. You might try an `IF EXISTS %WINDIR%\System32\ICACLS.EXE (execute icacls)` type of thing.

Comment: I got win7 working with: "icacls file.log /grant Users:RW". Will work on XP next. After that I can have the installer distinguish between the OSs.

Comment: My XP is having issues. The box was part of a domain, so I'm not sure if that is leading to the issue or not. Current when I run the command I get "Invalid arguments.Displays or modifies access control lists (ACLs) of files" I've checked the format several times and all looks good. I've read that sometimes I have to try to revoke the rights first using "/e /r", which seems to be more responsive, but yields "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.". The group I'm trying to do this for is "Users", which is a local group... any insight is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can get an NTAccount object, and get the file's FileSecurity object, and use the FileSecurity object's AddAccessRule method to set permissions.

See the MSDN forum post below for more detailed instructions.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c513ca26-9bf8-4e39-a993-4ebf90aaece6/